# create update form with v-model and data come to state vue2

Tags: javascript, forms, vuejs2, vuex, v-model

I have a form that I want to pre-fill to update my users' information. The data comes from the state (vuex) and is retrieved from my API so it is asynchronous.

How can I pre-fill the form with the data when it is only available a few seconds after the form is loaded?

For the example Here is the behavior of my form:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    stateFirstname: null,
    stateLastname: null,
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      // send form data to my API
      console.log(this.firstname, this.lastname);
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // Data in state come from my API and is async 
    // I simulate here its behavior
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.stateFirstname = "John";
      this.stateLastname = "Doe";
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input v-model="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input v-model="lastname" id="lastname" />
    <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

For the moment I use this solution but the code seems very heavy for a simple update form.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    stateFirstname: null,
    stateLastname: null,
  },
  watch: {
    stateFirstname(v) {
      this.firstname = v;
    },
    stateLastname(v) {
      this.lastname = v;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      // send form data to my API
      console.log(this.firstname, this.lastname);
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (this.stateFistname) this.firstname = this.stateFirstname;
    if (this.stateLastname) this.lastname = this.stateLastname;
    
    // Data in state come from my API and is async 
    // I simulate here its behavior
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.stateFirstname = "John";
      this.stateLastname = "Doe";
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input v-model="firstname" id="firstname" />
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input v-model="lastname" id="lastname" />
    <button type="submit">UPDATE</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a listener on your state and inside you fill your model.

```
   watch: {
      stateFirstname(value) {
         this.firstname = value;
      },
      stateLastname(value) {
         this.lastname = value;
      }
   },
```

if not, you can create computed ones based on your vuex store

```
computed: {
    firstname: {
      /* By default get() is used */
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.stateFirstname
      },
      /* We add a setter */
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('updateStateFirstname', value)
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case, you need to remove `firstname` from your component data

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but it didn't seem very optimized.

Comment: Since you are retrieving the data from the store, I think this is a good solution. if not, I just edited my answer by adding an other method